# Datetime error migrating MS Access to MySQL with Workbench

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I am trying to migrate an MS Access database to MySQL Server using Workbench, but Workbench generates errors in the SQL CREATE script, which causes some tables to fail to be created. Most are of the following form:

> Too-big precision 19 specified for 'TransDate'. Maximum is 6..
>
> SQL Error: 1426

Referring to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbName`.`tblName` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `TransDate` DATETIME(19) NULL,
    `ClientID` INT(10) NULL,
    ...
```

As you can see, it also generates integer types with deprecated display width syntax, which is something I would like to avoid as well.

How can I make Workbench generate a script that avoids these problems?

**EDIT**

I am aware that the script can be manually edited in the Create Target Results stage; however there are many tables that have these errors, and I can't see any way to edit them with a text editor, so I am looking for a solution wherein Workbench generates the correct script automatically.

Comment: Did you tried this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html  ? It works good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Manual Editing tab, I found an option to edit column mappings, which allows you to change multiple columns of the same type across the script all at once. Pick Column Mappings from the drop down window, and right click on a row that corresponds to the type you want to remap. Then choose 'Find and Replace Target Type' and provide the types you want to map.

Comment: It's bizarre that it defaults to 19 which isn't even supported in MySQL. The documentation even says the maximum preicision is 6. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html